# UITextView shouldChangeCharactersInRange in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, textview

Trying to disable/enable the next button (which begins disabled on the storyboard) based on how many characters are in the textView field. It isn't working, which makes me think that only the textField has this feature and not the textView (they were really lazy with developing the textView field).

I have an outlet connected for the textView and next button:

```
@IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!
@IBOutlet weak var nextButton: UIBarButtonItem!

func textView(textView: UITextView, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    let oldText: NSString = textView.text
    let newText: NSString = oldText.stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: string)

    if newText.length > 0 {

        nextButton.enabled = true

    } else {

        nextButton.enabled = false
    }

    return true

}
```

How do I get this to work, because it just completely ignores it even if it compiles without errors.

Comment: Did you set your text view's delegate? And are you sure your outlets are linked properly?

Comment: Also have you set a breakpoint or adding a println to see if the method is being called?

Comment: I did use println, it's not being called. I did set the delegate. I tried Googling this but there's absolutely nothing about UITextView and this shouldChangeCharactersInRange function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Requires UITextViewDelegate reference in class line:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate {

}
```

AND it also requires a referencing outlet from the view controller to the textView delegate. Select the view controller, click on outlets, drag from referencing outlet to the textView, click delegate.

Answer (score 2):

The used delegates method was wrong.

`shouldChangeCharactersInRange` is for `UITextField` not `UITextView`

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string;
```

Method for UITextView

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text;
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably you have not set the viewController as the delegate of the textField.
There are 2 ways to do that ...
1) Override viewDidLoad and mention textField.delegate = self

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    textField.delegate = self
}
```

2) open the corresponding storyBoard, control drag the textField to the viewController and select **delegate** from the pop-up.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define the function name with the correct name, otherwise it will not be recognised and not triggered

func textView(textView: UITextView, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

You'll have to include the UITextViewDelegate reference in the class definition, so that the deligate it assigned to the class:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate {
```

And you have to link the textView delegate (eg. in the viewDidLoad):

```
textView.delegate = self
```